# Saída desconfigurada no Atom

Tags: c++

Utilizo atom + gpp compiler para estudar c++ no windows. Quando utilizo acentos a saída é toda bagunçada.
Existe alguma maneira de permitir a saída de acentos?

Obrigado pela ajuda

[image]

Comment: O problema não é o código mas sim o prompt que "não" mostra caracteres especiais, eu não consigo testar isso agora para dar uma resposta clara, mas esses dois links ([site da microsoft](https://answers.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/forum/all/como-resolver-o-problema-de-acentua%C3%A7%C3%A3o/0fc3ad39-10ce-4700-a6db-da44fda87057)) e esse  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1372218/4246164)  no stackoverflow em inglês explica o problema um pouco melhor.

Answer (score 0):

Poderás incluir a biblioteca "locale" ou a função "setmode", tem aqui dois links que o ajudam e explica: https://www.portugal-a-programar.pt/forums/topic/63166-resolvido-acentos-e-caracteres-especiais-no-c/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17641718/how-to-output-unicode-characters-in-c-c/17641842#17641842

Comment: já havia encontrado esses dois links e não tinha resolvido meu problema, obrigado.